# Proton Antiproton collision

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, protons

Can it be possible to form an electron-positron pair from a proton-antiproton collision through the following interaction?
$$p+\bar{p}\rightarrow[X]\rightarrow e^-+e^+$$
Where [X] is a particular unstable intermediate and will decay into electron-positron pair with few microseconds.

Comment: What is exact purpose of the question? Do you accept processes where e+e- pair is produced among other particles? What kind of energy range of protons and anti-protons do we consider and is it relevant for you? Finally, why microsecond scale? This limits you to weak processes and makes this improbable reaction even more improbable.

Comment: @user1079505 The momentum range of each incident proton and antiproton is 10GeV/c to 20GeV./c

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly possible, but extremely unlikely.

It can happen through direct resonances, as in $p \overline p \to J/\psi \to e^+e^-$, or through virtual particles, as in $p \overline p \to \gamma^* \to e^+e^-$.

(Timescales for the intermediate state are much shorter than microseconds.)

It doesn't happen very often because the proton and antiproton can annihilate through the strong interaction, so reactions like the second are scarce compared to annihilation to pions.   Also because at high energies the proton should be thought of as 3 quarks, and a reaction like the first involves all six of them co-operating, so is scarce compared to processes where only one quark pair annihilates and the other 4 are merely 'spectators'.

Answer (score 13):

You are describing a resonance in the scattering of protons on antiprotons. This is the measurement of the total crossection as found in the [particle data group](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2015/hadronic-xsections/rpp2014-pp_pbarp_plots.pdf)

[image: protonantiproton]

No resonances are seen, so the answer is that no, there is no such resonance in the region of energy explored up to now, to go into the probability of its having an $e^+ e^-$ decay.

In contrast  [electron positron](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/reviews/rpp2019-rev-cross-section-plots.pdf) scattering  has a large number of resonances.

[image: elpos]

which will have a decay channel into electron positron pairs.

This difference is not surprising, because protons and antiprotons are composite particles and their scattering products have to follow conservation of quantum numbers of their components, which happens by pairing quarks with antiquarks, at least three pairs. One pair could be a resonance from the $e^+e^-$ plot , decaying to electron positron, but there will be other products of the scattering.

As  an example let us take the Z boson which [has a decay](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2018/listings/rpp2018-list-z-boson.pdf) into  three pairs of quarks, in principle, such pairs could form in the complicated phase space of the [proton](https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/largehadroncolliderfaq/whats-a-proton-anyway/) and antiproton, but they would have to be within the  mass of the Z , in order to have a probability to decay only  into an  $e^+ e^-$ pair. The measured cross section  reflects how improbable this is.

Comment: "No resonances are seen, so the answer is that no, there is no such resonance in the region of energy explored up to now". Is it not possible that there could be an extremely narrow resonance?

Comment: @PeterBingham  No, it would have been detected. Look at the narrowness in the e+e- plot

Answer (score 6):

I would like to add to the already excellent answers of Anna_v and RogerJBarlow, that usually one does not get a pure $e^+e^-$ end-state, instead amongst a lot of hadronic particles (typically mesons) one might also find an  $e^+e^-$ pair.
This is because from each in-going proton/anti-proton one quark/anti-quark might create (mostly via an intermediate state) the $e^+e^-$ pair, whereas the 2x2 other quarks/anti-quarks are spectator particles which will in the end hadronize, i.e. create jets of particles that contain the spectator quarks and if enough energy is available contain further quarks generated by the hadronization.

So at the end one might observe a $e^+e^-$ pair amongst a swarm of many hadrons, it is then up to the experimentator to detect the $e^+e^-$ pair unambigously amongst outgoing hadrons.